# Como definir largura da navbar

Tags: html, css, html5

Caros, estou desenvolvendo um Menu com Submenus, mas não consigo definir uma largura para a navbar de forma que ela fique no no tamanho da tela!

```
'<style type="text/css">

/*Configurações Padrões*/
ul.menu, .menu li, .menu a{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; text-decoration:none;}
ul.menu ul{ position:absolute; display:none; box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #333;}

/* Configurações nivel 1*/
ul.menu{ float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px; border-radius:5px; padding:0 5px;}
.menu li{ float:left; width:auto; position:relative;}
.menu li a{ display:block; padding:0 20px; line-height:45px; height:45px; float:left; transition:all 0.1s linear; }

/* Configurações nivel 2*/
.menu li:hover > ul.submenu-1{ display:block; top:45px; left:0; padding:5px; width:200px; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;   }
.menu ul.submenu-1 a{  width:160px; padding:0 20px; border-radius:5px;  }

/* Configurações nivel 2*/
.menu li:hover > ul.submenu-2{ display:block; top:0; left:195px; padding:5px; width:200px;  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px; }
.menu ul.submenu-2 a{  width:160px; padding:0 20px; border-radius:5px; }

/* Configurações nivel 3*/
.menu li:hover > ul.submenu-3{ display:block; top:0; left:195px; padding:5px; width:200px;  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px; }
.menu ul.submenu-3 a{  width:160px; padding:0 20px; border-radius:5px; }


/*Configurações de cores*/

/*nivel 1*/
.menu{background:#CCC; }
.menu a{ color:#000;}
.menu li:hover > a{ background:#999;  color:#fff;}

/*nivel 2*/
.submenu-1{ background:#999;}
.submenu-1 a{color:#fff;}
.submenu-1 li:hover > a{ background:#666; }

/*nivel 3*/
.submenu-2{ background:#666;}
.submenu-2 a{color:#fff;}
.submenu-2 li:hover > a{ background:#333; }

/*nivel 3*/
.submenu-3{ background:#333;}
.submenu-3 a{color:#fff;}
.submenu-3 li:hover > a{ background:#000; }


</style>




<ul class="menu"> <!-- Esse é o 1 nivel ou o nivel principal -->
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1"> <!-- Esse é o 2 nivel ou o primeiro Drop Down -->
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                    <ul class="submenu-2"> <!-- Esse é o 3 nivel ou o Segundo Drop Down -->
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 6</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu-3"> <!-- Esse é o 4 nivel ou o Terceiro Drop Down -->
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 7</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 8</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 9</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>


</ul>'
```

Comment: Mas vc quer que ele tenha a largura da tela é isso?

Comment: Sim! Gostaria que ficasse de ponta a ponta da tela!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc tem que colocar o `UL` com `100%` de largura, porém como ela também tem um `padding` a direita e esquerda vc precisa colocar `box-sizing:borde-box` para esse `padding` não se somar a largura gerando uma barra de rolagem horizontal desnecessária... Além disso tb remova o `margin` do `body` para a barra realmente colar nos cantos da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código da imagem acima:

```css
/*Configurações Padrões*/
ul.menu, .menu li, .menu a{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; text-decoration:none;}
ul.menu ul{ position:absolute; display:none; box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #333;}

/* Configurações nivel 1*/
ul.menu{ float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px; border-radius:5px; padding:0 5px;}
.menu li{ float:left; width:auto; position:relative;}
.menu li a{ display:block; padding:0 20px; line-height:45px; height:45px; float:left; transition:all 0.1s linear; }

/* Configurações nivel 2*/
.menu li:hover > ul.submenu-1{ display:block; top:45px; left:0; padding:5px; width:200px; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;   }
.menu ul.submenu-1 a{  width:160px; padding:0 20px; border-radius:5px;  }

/* Configurações nivel 2*/
.menu li:hover > ul.submenu-2{ display:block; top:0; left:195px; padding:5px; width:200px;  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px; }
.menu ul.submenu-2 a{  width:160px; padding:0 20px; border-radius:5px; }

/* Configurações nivel 3*/
.menu li:hover > ul.submenu-3{ display:block; top:0; left:195px; padding:5px; width:200px;  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px; }
.menu ul.submenu-3 a{  width:160px; padding:0 20px; border-radius:5px; }


/*Configurações de cores*/

/*nivel 1*/
.menu{background:#CCC; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}
.menu a{ color:#000;}
.menu li:hover > a{ background:#999;  color:#fff;}

/*nivel 2*/
.submenu-1{ background:#999;}
.submenu-1 a{color:#fff;}
.submenu-1 li:hover > a{ background:#666; }

/*nivel 3*/
.submenu-2{ background:#666;}
.submenu-2 a{color:#fff;}
.submenu-2 li:hover > a{ background:#333; }

/*nivel 3*/
.submenu-3{ background:#333;}
.submenu-3 a{color:#fff;}
.submenu-3 li:hover > a{ background:#000; }

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu"> <!-- Esse é o 1 nivel ou o nivel principal -->
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1"> <!-- Esse é o 2 nivel ou o primeiro Drop Down -->
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                    <ul class="submenu-2"> <!-- Esse é o 3 nivel ou o Segundo Drop Down -->
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 6</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu-3"> <!-- Esse é o 4 nivel ou o Terceiro Drop Down -->
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 7</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 8</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 9</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>


</ul>
```

Comment: Entendi @hugocsl! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @PCP84 legal que deu certo! 